# Есть проект node.js,как использовать библиотеку планировщика node-quartz, чтобы запускать проект с определенным промежутком времени?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть проект node.js,как использовать библиотеку планировщика  node-quartz, чтобы запускать проект с определенным промежутком времени? Где почитать можно про это, или пример использования.

Comment: Если я правильно нашел библиотеку  [xjodoin/node-quartz](https://github.com/xjodoin/node-quartz), то она не обновлялась уже 6 лет. Я бы не советовал ее использовать. У вас проект в котором определенную задачу нужно выполнять с промежутком или какой-то скрипт на Node.js, который нужно запускать с определенным промежутком?

Comment: @rtk,Да. есть сервис на node.js,который надо запускать каждые(5 мин)

Comment: причем таких сервисов несколько

Comment: @RTK, т.е. как я понимаю, мне нужно написать отдельный сервис, который бы с определенной периодичностью запускал другие. какая библиотека наиболее подойдет для решения такой задачи?

Comment: можно попробовать  [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron), она очень похожа на `node-quartz`, но в актуальном состоянии